# Is it possible to create DNA of a species that could be any animal

Tags: dna, synthetic-biology

I was thinking about a fiction world in which all animal (at least vertebrate) could crossbred because they share same number and layout of chromosome but differ in hereditary detail (like human skin color) and/or using epigenetic modifications.

Is it actually possible? And how large of DNA it could be to code all vertebrate form and function?

I'm programmer so I just think DNA as a code. And it seem we could refactor and reuse most of DNA code between tetrapod species (also between arthropod-arthropod species)

Comment: I don't really understand your question. Are you asking something like "what is the Shanon's entropy of all vertebrates DNA put together?"

Comment: Cell fusions could be done in plants; don't know does it happen to animals or not. Usually animals can't support chromosomal aberration. They die.  But most plants can easily support chromosomal aberration.

Comment: I am voting to close as unclear. In addition of the post being unclear to me, my rough understand of the question in the post does not match the one in the title.

Comment: The very similarities in number and layout of chromosomes that allows animals to breed with each other are the same similarities that cause them to end up with reasonably similar phenotypes. As soon as the genomes are too different to breed with each other, the phenotypes of the animals are so different that we categorise them as different species (usually). Therefore, I believe the question that you're really asking is, "can epigenetic control alone result in phenotypes so different that they would seem like different species?"

Comment: (Because their genetic similarity is what makes them de facto the same species)

Comment: @Armatus That's right as my first question. What I meant is not just epigenetic but also hereditary like lactic tolerance. But on wider scale, such as same specie being ruminants herbivore in one area but carnivore in other place but still able to mate if they met. What I want to know is are there any impossible trait that can't be code in the same layout like that in DNA

Comment: "same specie being ruminants herbivore in one area but carnivore in other place" ... do you know any such example?

Comment: Probably the OP is asking "is it possible to write/formulate a general genetic-scheme for a group-of-organism (say all vertebrates)?". Is that?

Comment: Different species of Vertebrates do-not have same number of chromosome. even-if some have same number of chromosomes, it is just co-incidence... they are separate species. However, on chromosomes there are homologous sequences

Comment: @AlwaysConfused I press upvote at your right comment. As I was state that I am thinking about fictional alien (parallel) world, I just want it scientifically possible

Comment: @Thaina Please edit and improve your question because from its language it is creating so many possible meanings (ambiguous) to me.  btw for a virtual/theoretical "vertebrate" would behave like-to "real" vertebrates (otherwise we'll not use the term vertebrate for them). or if you write a  story then it is different thing. you could write a story about a human without no DNA... in story anything is possible. However, there are some technical mistakes in your question (or I had read them correctly). Write in simple way.

Comment: If I even could theoretically formulate a general formula for a large taxonomic group with some specific-portions (common for all them) and variable portions (that are different in different subset-taxa) ;  whenever I would practically   make one, there would nothing "variable". It will then become an individual with very specific genetic structure, that could not mate with so-many other kinds of organism.

Answer (score 1):

Suppose genome A generates organism oA and genome B generates organism oB. Their phenotypes pA and pB are quite different from each other.

Because genome A and B are not similar enough, organism oA and oB cannot sexually produce viable offspring.

Your question seems to boil down to: "Would it be possible to generate oA/pA and oB/pB from genome A, or a genome similar enough to genome A such that it can still sexually reproduce with genome A?"

So you basically ask whether any genome A could simultaneously produce pA and pB under different external conditions.

Answer: Possibly? The genes involved in the development of organisms typically don't respond to external stimuli but to genes which were active before them (in time). Various genes produce proteins which sense temperature, osmotic pressure or particular chemical species or ions. If those were factored into very early developmental programs, feeding into transcription factors to modify gene expression according to external factors, the same genome could produce drastically different organisms.

To speculate more about this yourself, it would probably help to go away from a code-based understanding of DNA and think more about what it is physically and biologically. Unlike computer programs, DNA "programs" can modify themselves and other programs or the functions they execute.

Biologically, DNA is an information carrier that is transcribed into RNA, which can have functions of its own and/or be translated into proteins. DNA interacts very tightly (physically) with a lot of RNA and protein components, and most things that happen in cells and tissues around them end up modifying the way DNA is handled in some way. Keywords that you could look up are "gene expression", "gene regulation" and "developmental biology".